# Display number of posts via adress bar?

Tags: posts, search

when i call this link ;

```
?s=key&order=ASC
```

wp display my search query order by ASC.

```
?s=key&order=ASC&number=10
```

how can we display whatever i want to display postnumber like 10 or more ?

is that possible ?

Comment: Could you precise your question ? What do you want to display ? The search results starting at the 10th one ? Or the post that has the id of 10 ?

Comment: @FabienQuatravaux i want to display both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking to change the number of posts from 10 to something else, you can do one of the following

1) Submit the search query as

```
?s=key&order=ASC&posts_per_page=5
```

You can achieve this by adding hidden fields to the form. Just change the number to whatever you want

2) Go to Settings > Reading, change the setting there. This will change the setting for all the pages though

3) Add this to your theme's functions.php or in a plugin

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_posts_on_search');
function change_posts_on_search($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search())
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 5); // change the number here
}
```

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
    <select name="posts_per_page">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>20</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This form does that work. Basically it's same as the first option above. But except for the hidden field, it shows the field to the user allowing for changes.

Comment: You welcome. BTW, not Aggard :P

Comment: Sorry about that @Mridul Aggarwal by the way, i have another question, how can we add a select option box for this query.

when user select 10 i want to display 10 results when he select 20 i want to display 20 resulst ? 

could you give me an example please. ?

Comment: updated the answer